# HTTP 404 is returned if method is not defined in service

Tags: servicestack

Why is `HTTP 404` returned instead of `HTTP 405` in response to a valid URI with undefined method? How could I change that to return `HTTP 405`?

Comment: When you say that, you mean `/route` exists, but you call `GET` instead of `POST`? I get a `404`.

Comment: @Tyrsius: thx, corrected the post. It's really 404.

Comment: I feel like `404` is the correct error here.

Comment: @Tyrsius: Can't agree, see [RFC 2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html) 10.4.5 vs 10.4.6

Comment: Good point. I would file this as an issue on the github page.